# Dynamic Ajax Form withsubmission

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

i am trying to build a customer list with using mysql,php and ajax. i currently have a list of customers displayed on the page and my end goal is to be able to create a new customer and edit the other customers on the same page.

i have a form for creating a new customer and then a form for each customer listed on the page its basically the same form as the new customer but with and id on the end of the name tags to make sure each name is different from the other and one updates and one creates see below

```
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form  name='frm_details' id='frm_details' action=''>
<input type='text' class='form-control' name='box1' required>
<input type='text' class='form-control' name='box2' required>   
<input type='submit' value='Save' > 
</form>

<form  name='frm_details' id='frm_details' action=''>
<input type='text' class='form-control' name='box1_2465' required>
<input type='text' class='form-control' name='box2_2465' required>  
<input type='submit' value='Save' > 
</form>                             


    <script>
        $(function() {
            $('#frm_details').on('submit', function(event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                $.ajax({
                    url: '/limitless/functions2.php',
                    type: 'post',
                    dataType: 'json',                       
                    data: $(this).serialize(),
                      success: function(data) {
                           if(data.status == '1')
                            {
                                $('#info').addClass('alert alert-danger no-border').html(data.message);
                            } 
                           if(data.status == '2')
                            {
                                $('#info').addClass('alert alert-danger no-border').html(data.message);
                            }                               
                        }  
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
```

this works flawlessly for the creation of a new customer however when i submit the second form to edit the customer with the id in the name tag it fails to execute the ajax is there any chance someone could point out where i am going wrong if possible i would like to keep a single ajax request just with the form id changed $('#frm_details2465')

Comment: id must be unique  use classes instead

Comment: any chance of an example im new to ajax, i really appreciate you taking the time to help me with my issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1st:** id must be unique as I said

**2nd:**  you can change Ids like so

in html

```
<form  name='frm_details' id='frm_details1' action=''>
<form  name='frm_details' id='frm_details2' action=''>
```

in js

```
$('form[id^=frm_details]')
```

or you can use classes

```
<form  name='frm_details' class='frm_details' id='frm_details1' action=''>
<form  name='frm_details' class='frm_details' id='frm_details2' action=''>
```

and in js

```
$('form.frm_details')
```

Comment: thinking about it now how would you save it to the database as the original name was box1 which is what functions2.php looks for however box1_2465 is now what it gets